# How to produce a JSON Schema without having a java object

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am currently trying to create a JSON Schema for every controller my API shows in public.
In all my controllers, I have a java object behind them. I use my object's fields to get guided for the creation of each JSON Schema.
But I also have 1 controller, used to keep statistics (ratings, favourites) which doesn't have a java object behind it. This controller has only GET methods.

For example, let's talk about ratings. It accepts an id for the object I want to see its rating, plus an interval (Day, Month, Year), it executes some operations and it returns a Map like this:

```
{
  "2018-12": 2.5,
  "2019-01": 3.8333333,
  "2019-02": 3,
  "2019-03": 3,
  "2019-04": 3,
  "2019-05": 4,
  "2019-06": 3,
  "2019-07": 2
}
```

So in 2018-12 the object with the specific id got 2.5 ratings in total.

And to be more specific.
In the UI, when a user rates something, I call another controller called EventController. This controller saves who rated, when and what he rated. When I want to see a specific rating, I call the StatsController. StatsController calls StatsManager which get the info required (from EventManager), execute its operations and create the rating it' ll finally show to the user.

But my EventController is @ApiIgnore on the API. That means it doesn't appear in the API, so I don't need a JSON Schema for the Event.java class. I need for the Stats though.

How can I create a JSON Schema for my Stats Controller? Is it even possible to create a schema if you don't have a java object?

I hope I explained it well.

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't this depend on what the library you are using expects? I'm not sure anyone can help you without providing further information, including what library you are using for JSON Schema, and some example code of what you have so far.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198873/flutter-get-data-from-complex-json/57199326#57199326