# Flutter get Data from complex json

Tags: json, flutter

I want the "title" of this json

I want only the title in item.
I can get every Data over items like kind or etag but items is null.
How can I get the title??

```dart
var data = await http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={id}&maxResults=5&order=date&type=video&key={key}");
var jsonData =  json.decode(data.body);
String title = jsonData["items"][0]["title"];
```

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/g32qWHUfh9ZGLFfaJ4eAIWqe5As\"",
    "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
    "regionCode": "DE",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 207,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
            "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/IPag1MLLCZWNOan8xL200XduRjk\"",
            "id": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "iWkAYZyrrWc"
            },
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2019-07-24T15:59:15.000Z",
                "channelId": "UC7TZhmZOk5nxVjBozb2EW4w",
                "title": "Afterbuy Statistiken - Performance Analyse und Controlling für Onlinehändler!",
                "description": "Die Afterbuy Statistik ist ein Auswertungstool zur Analyse der Performance eines Onlinehändlers im E-Commerce Markt. Wenn du den Mehrwert dieser Afterbuy ...",
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iWkAYZyrrWc/default.jpg",
                        "width": 120,
                        "height": 90
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iWkAYZyrrWc/mqdefault.jpg",
                        "width": 320,
                        "height": 180
                  }
              }
          }
        }
      ]
   };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed **snippet**:

```js
var title = jsonData()["items"][0].snippet["title"];
console.log(title);

function jsonData() {
   return {
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/g32qWHUfh9ZGLFfaJ4eAIWqe5As\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "DE",
  "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 207,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
      {
          "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
          "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/IPag1MLLCZWNOan8xL200XduRjk\"",
          "id": {
              "kind": "youtube#video",
              "videoId": "iWkAYZyrrWc"
          },
          "snippet": {
              "publishedAt": "2019-07-24T15:59:15.000Z",
              "channelId": "UC7TZhmZOk5nxVjBozb2EW4w",
              "title": "Afterbuy Statistiken - Performance Analyse und Controlling für Onlinehändler!",
              "description": "Die Afterbuy Statistik ist ein Auswertungstool zur Analyse der Performance eines Onlinehändlers im E-Commerce Markt. Wenn du den Mehrwert dieser Afterbuy ...",
              "thumbnails": {
                  "default": {
                      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iWkAYZyrrWc/default.jpg",
                      "width": 120,
                      "height": 90
                  },
                  "medium": {
                      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iWkAYZyrrWc/mqdefault.jpg",
                      "width": 320,
                      "height": 180
                  }
              }
          }
        }
      ]
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) website to generate the Model class for your response.

or you can also check this out: [JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

and use it like below:

```
// If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
return YourModel.fromJson(json.decode(data.body));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the title and you don't want to create a model(you really should IMO)

Pseudo code

```
List<String> titlesList=new List<String>();
if(jsonData.length != 0){
   if(jsonData["items"]!=null ){
     List itemsList = jsonData["items"];
      for(var item in itemsList){
       String title = item["snippet"]["title"];
       //ideally here you create your snippet object using a model and add it to a list of models
       //titlesList.add(title)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model as below.

// To parse this JSON data, do
    //
    //     final result = resultFromJson(jsonString);

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Result {
    String kind;
    String etag;
    String nextPageToken;
    String regionCode;
    PageInfo pageInfo;
    List<Item> items;

    Result({
        this.kind,
        this.etag,
        this.nextPageToken,
        this.regionCode,
        this.pageInfo,
        this.items,
    });

    factory Result.fromRawJson(String str) => Result.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Result(
        kind: json["kind"] == null ? null : json["kind"],
        etag: json["etag"] == null ? null : json["etag"],
        nextPageToken: json["nextPageToken"] == null ? null : json["nextPageToken"],
        regionCode: json["regionCode"] == null ? null : json["regionCode"],
        pageInfo: json["pageInfo"] == null ? null : PageInfo.fromJson(json["pageInfo"]),
        items: json["items"] == null ? null : new List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "kind": kind == null ? null : kind,
        "etag": etag == null ? null : etag,
        "nextPageToken": nextPageToken == null ? null : nextPageToken,
        "regionCode": regionCode == null ? null : regionCode,
        "pageInfo": pageInfo == null ? null : pageInfo.toJson(),
        "items": items == null ? null : new List<dynamic>.from(items.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Item {
    String kind;
    String etag;
    Id id;
    Snippet snippet;

    Item({
        this.kind,
        this.etag,
        this.id,
        this.snippet,
    });

    factory Item.fromRawJson(String str) => Item.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Item(
        kind: json["kind"] == null ? null : json["kind"],
        etag: json["etag"] == null ? null : json["etag"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : Id.fromJson(json["id"]),
        snippet: json["snippet"] == null ? null : Snippet.fromJson(json["snippet"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "kind": kind == null ? null : kind,
        "etag": etag == null ? null : etag,
        "id": id == null ? null : id.toJson(),
        "snippet": snippet == null ? null : snippet.toJson(),
    };
}

class Id {
    String kind;
    String videoId;

    Id({
        this.kind,
        this.videoId,
    });

    factory Id.fromRawJson(String str) => Id.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Id.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Id(
        kind: json["kind"] == null ? null : json["kind"],
        videoId: json["videoId"] == null ? null : json["videoId"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "kind": kind == null ? null : kind,
        "videoId": videoId == null ? null : videoId,
    };
}

class Snippet {
    DateTime publishedAt;
    String channelId;
    String title;
    String description;
    Thumbnails thumbnails;

    Snippet({
        this.publishedAt,
        this.channelId,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.thumbnails,
    });

    factory Snippet.fromRawJson(String str) => Snippet.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Snippet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Snippet(
        publishedAt: json["publishedAt"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["publishedAt"]),
        channelId: json["channelId"] == null ? null : json["channelId"],
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        description: json["description"] == null ? null : json["description"],
        thumbnails: json["thumbnails"] == null ? null : Thumbnails.fromJson(json["thumbnails"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "publishedAt": publishedAt == null ? null : publishedAt.toIso8601String(),
        "channelId": channelId == null ? null : channelId,
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "description": description == null ? null : description,
        "thumbnails": thumbnails == null ? null : thumbnails.toJson(),
    };
}

class Thumbnails {
    Default thumbnailsDefault;
    Default medium;

    Thumbnails({
        this.thumbnailsDefault,
        this.medium,
    });

    factory Thumbnails.fromRawJson(String str) => Thumbnails.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Thumbnails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Thumbnails(
        thumbnailsDefault: json["default"] == null ? null : Default.fromJson(json["default"]),
        medium: json["medium"] == null ? null : Default.fromJson(json["medium"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "default": thumbnailsDefault == null ? null : thumbnailsDefault.toJson(),
        "medium": medium == null ? null : medium.toJson(),
    };
}

class Default {
    String url;
    int width;
    int height;

    Default({
        this.url,
        this.width,
        this.height,
    });

    factory Default.fromRawJson(String str) => Default.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Default.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Default(
        url: json["url"] == null ? null : json["url"],
        width: json["width"] == null ? null : json["width"],
        height: json["height"] == null ? null : json["height"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "url": url == null ? null : url,
        "width": width == null ? null : width,
        "height": height == null ? null : height,
    };
}

class PageInfo {
    int totalResults;
    int resultsPerPage;

    PageInfo({
        this.totalResults,
        this.resultsPerPage,
    });

    factory PageInfo.fromRawJson(String str) => PageInfo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory PageInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new PageInfo(
        totalResults: json["totalResults"] == null ? null : json["totalResults"],
        resultsPerPage: json["resultsPerPage"] == null ? null : json["resultsPerPage"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "totalResults": totalResults == null ? null : totalResults,
        "resultsPerPage": resultsPerPage == null ? null : resultsPerPage,
    };
}
```

Next do,

```
var data = await http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={id}&maxResults=5&order=date&type=video&key={key}");
var jsonData =  json.decode(data.body);
return Result.fromJson(jsonData);
```

It should work at this point